# scrapy can't find text() content

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I can't understand why scrapy can't see some //div/text() on page http://www.alize.gen.tr/index.php?is=urun_detay&id=37 . for examle:

```
scrapy view http://www.alize.gen.tr/index.php?is=urun_detay&id=37
```

and

```
scrapy shell http://www.alize.gen.tr/index.php?is=urun_detay&id=37

>>> hxs.select("//td[@class='urun_adi']/div/text()").extract()
```

returns [u'\r\n'] but must be [u'\r\nANGORA GOLD']

where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
stav@maia:~$ scrapy shell "http://www.alize.gen.tr/index.php?is=urun_detay&id=37"
2013-03-28 20:36:39-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.17.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
...
>>> hxs.select("//td[@class='urun_adi']/div/text()").extract()
[u'\r\nANGORA GOLD']
```

What version Scrapy are you using?

```
stav@maia:~$ scrapy version -v
Scrapy  : 0.17.0
lxml    : 2.3.2.0
libxml2 : 2.7.8
Twisted : 11.1.0
Python  : 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) - [GCC 4.6.3]
Platform: Linux-3.2.0-39-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
```

Comment: Scrapy  : 0.16.4
lxml    : 3.1.0.0
libxml2 : 2.9.0
Twisted : 12.3.0
Python  : 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Platform: Windows-XP-5.1.2600-SP3

Comment: I tried to use linux version and everything works fine! Thank you! Scrapy  : 0.17.0-196-gb0ea457
lxml    : 2.3.5.0
libxml2 : 2.8.0
Twisted : 12.2.0
Python  : 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) - [GCC 4.7.2]
Platform: Linux-3.5.0-17-generic-i686-with-LinuxMint-14-nadia

Comment: Rolando mentioned on the [users list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scrapy-users/ywa6FJleTx4/WD9Tvb3NKOoJ) that he has a [commit on github](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy/commit/92d443c7965263f0fa6cd54d9d8446e0c244e059) that allows for callback in the `crawl` command.